# Jquery Post PHP always sending Success Response

Tags: php, jquery

I'm sending some data via Post to a php file, and I'm always retrieving a "success" in Jquery status even though the PHP is clearly sending back an error message.

What's the reason behind that?

```
$.post('post.php',
    {
    post1:somevariable1,
    post2:somevariable2,
    post3:somevariable3
    },
    function(response,status){
        if(status == "success") {
            //success message (I'm always getting this)
        }
        else {
            //error message
        }


    });
```

**Post.php**

```
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo "error!!";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true)); // This is what PHP is sending

} else {
    echo "Success!!"; 
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);  
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check DevTools network. See what the status of the request is. It may be a successful status.

Comment: It sure is sending a 200 OK status back. I tried adding in headers and I still get the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the other answers, your PHP file is completing and then returning a success status and so you always see `status=='success'`. What you actually want to do is check the value in `response`. I would recommend doing something like:

```
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'reason' => sqlsrv_errors()));
    exit;  
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);  
}
```

Then in your jquery do this:

```
$.post('post.php',
    {
    post1:somevariable1,
    post2:somevariable2,
    post3:somevariable3
    },
    function(response,status){
        let result = $.parseJSON(response);
        if (result.success) {
            echo "success!";
        }
        else {
            echo "error: " + result.reason;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what I resolved with in the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sending the result of an operation as the return of a request, simply check the response in the `success` callback`

```
$.post('post.php',
    {
    post1:somevariable1,
    post2:somevariable2,
    post3:somevariable3
    },
    function(response,status){
        if(response.status == "success") { // Here I'm checking the `response` argument
            //success message (I'm always getting this)
        }
        else {
            //error message
        }
});
```

Where I've made the assumption that your response is being sent back from PHP as an object with the property `status`:

```
{
  status: "success"|"error"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that there is not a problem going on, the server is giving you a response of 200, because it did'nt find an error.

try using headers inside the condition where you want it to fail like

```
header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
exit;
//or try return false;
```

Comment: Yes it's sending a 200 OK status back, even after I add in the header.

Comment: If I put this inside the php IF ELSE statement, the page will still return a 200 OK unless I put this code at the very beginning.

Comment: try putting exit or return false, or die at the end of the file, i edited the anwser

Comment: Still a 200 OK. Interestingly enough, if I put the header at the very beginning of the page (whether or not the actual execution is a success), Jquery will not give me an error message either. it gives back no message, while Firebug will show a Post in red color and a 500 Internal Error Message.

Answer (score 0):

The post.php is responding with status 200 with a response. The browser/js doesn't check what text you are sending in the response.

You can set the header to let the browser/just know about the error:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
```

Comment: this is the exact same answer i gave :/